# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n^2+x^4\cos(nx)}{n^4+x^2}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, solution-verification

Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n^2 + x^4\cos(nx)}{n^4+x^2}$ converges to a continuous function $f :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$

My attempt: Let $f_n(x)=\frac{3n^2+x^4\cos(nx)}{n^4+x^2}$

$|f_n(x)|\leq\frac{3n^2+x^4}{n^4}$.  Let $a_n=\frac{3n^2+x^4}{n^4}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=3$. By comparison test both the series converge or diverge together.

By $p$ test $ b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent. This implies $a_n$ is convergent.

By WM test $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly. We know that it converges to a continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should localize to an arbitrary fixed closed interval $[a,b]$, and then apply Weierstrass M-Test, the upper bound is then $\dfrac{3n^{2}+b^{4}}{n^{4}}$, there should not be involved with any $x$.

So it converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ and hence the series is continuous on $[a,b]$, and then one can extend $[a,b]$ to include every point to be a continuity point.

Comment: Yeah, but $x \in \mathbb R$. Can we consider series on [a,b] instead of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For each $x$, pick an interval $[a,b]$ that containing $x$.

Comment: Means. I just prove over [a,b] then I write it converges over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: There are two things to be dealt with here. First, you need to prove the pointwise convergence, and actually you don't need uniform convergence to showing the pointwise thing. Second, you need to prove for the continuity, you really need uniform convergence. But continuity is a local property, you just need to prove the series is continuous at every point $x$. And you just need to prove for any closed interval containing $x$, you don't have to go over showing that it is uniform convergence on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\geq 1}[-n,n]$. It suffices to do for every $[-n,n]$.